# WPF combobox not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have an ObservableCollection in ViewModel which is bind to Combobox ItemsSource, this works fine. However, when I try to add or remove items in the above collection those changes are not reflected in Combobox. My ViewModel implements and INotifyPropertyChange and I can see in Debug mode that the collection is updated.

```
  <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                              ValidatesOnDataErrors=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" 
                              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
                              Validation.Error="Validation_Error"/>
```

This is my property:

```
  public ObservableCollection<string> MyCollection
    {
        get { return _myCollection; }
        set
        {
            _myCollection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyCollection");
        }
    }
```

The methods I use to update the MyCollection are:

```
MyCollection.Add(item): 
MyCollection.RemoveAt(3);
```

Comment: Have you double-checked that you aren't removing the same item you just added?  Also, you should not set `UpdateSourceTrigger` on your `ItemsSource` binding, as it should be a one-way binding and will never update the source.

Comment: The obvious answer is "can't reproduce". Try providing a minimal example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Have you checked if your view's DataContext being set to your viewmodel?

Comment: Have you tried setting Mode=TwoWay in the ItemsSource binding?

Comment: @Mike: I did change remove UpdateSourceTrigger and even Set Mode = OneWay ... same effect
jhenninger24: Yes otherwise my View wouldn't show data at all
Aaron : I think this is default option but I also Set Mode = TwoWay... same effect

Comment: There is an extra curly brace and double quote in the above example after: PropertyChanged}"     I'm not sure if this is in your actual code, but may be causing issues.